# How to handle the back button pressed, the image should be persistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having radio buttons, where on the click on them. I am changing the carousels. for that each carousel is enclosed in a div, on the document ready function, I am hiding all the caroursels. And on the click on the radio button, I am getting id of the input and showing the appropriate carousels and hiding the remaining. But the thing is, when they go forward to the next screen, and come back. The document ready function is getting executed and all the carousels are hidden now, but I want the previous carousel the user selected to be shown. How to handle this.

```
$(document).ready(function (){

            $('.car1').hide();
            $('.car2').hide();
            $('.car3').hide();
            $('.car4').hide();
    $(".changeprice").on("click", function() {
        var currentid = this.id;
        console.log(currentid);
        changecarousel(currentid);
    });
});



function changecarousel(id){



    switch(parseInt(id)){
        case 1:
            $('.car1').show();
            $('.car2').hide();
            $('.car3').hide();
            $('.car4').hide();
            console.log(id);
        break;

        case 2:
            $('.car1').hide();
            $('.car2').show();
            $('.car3').hide();
            $('.car4').hide();
            console.log(id);
        break;

        case 3:
            $('.car3').show();
            $('.car1').hide();
            $('.car2').hide();
            $('.car4').hide();
            console.log(id);

        break;

        case 4:
            $('.car4').show();
            $('.car1').hide();
            $('.car2').hide();
            $('.car3').hide();
            console.log(id);
        break;

    }

}
```

Comment: Please show us your code :)

Comment: Show the code, so people can help.

Comment: One minute .. I will post

Comment: I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code I think that will work for you.

```
    $(document).ready(function (){

$('.car1').hide();
$('.car2').hide();
$('.car3').hide();
$('.car4').hide();

if(localStorage.getItem("lastCarousel") != null){
  $('.'+localStorage.getItem("lastCarousel")).show();
  localStorage.removeItem("lastCarousel");
}
    $(".changeprice").on("click", function() {
    var currentid = this.id;
    console.log(currentid);
    changecarousel(currentid);
});
  });


  function changecarousel(id){

                $('.car1').hide();
      $('.car2').hide();
        $('.car3').hide();
        $('.car4').hide();

switch(parseInt(id)){
    case 1:
        $('.car1').show();
        localStorage.setItem("lastCarousel", "car1");
        console.log(id);
    break;

    case 2:
        $('.car2').show();
        localStorage.setItem("lastCarousel", "car2");
        console.log(id);
    break;

    case 3:
        $('.car3').show();
        localStorage.setItem("lastCarousel", "car3");
        console.log(id);

    break;

    case 4:
        $('.car4').show();
        localStorage.setItem("lastCarousel", "car4");
        console.log(id);
    break;

}

  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is [history.popState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate).

On your changecarousel function, need to store the id to some persistent state storage (recommended localStorage). Then on popState, looking for that stored id and invoke the changecarousel function again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use local storage to store the selection made by users. However this technology is implemented in newer browsers (so pay attentions to oldIEs support if it's mandatory)

```
localStorage.clear();
...
localStorage.setItem(foo, bar);
...
var bar = localStorage.getItem(foo);
```

Take a look at this code, it implements a persistent TODO-list using local storage. Try to add items to the list and reload the page.
http://codepen.io/BrandonJF/pen/KGwyC

P.S. Please remember that you have to clear the storage entries at the end of your wizard or whatever, so your users can easily start over. You might also have to clear the selection if the user left the page without going through all the steps.

UPDATE:

Thanks for providing code snippet, try to use this example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yedvXz

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.car1').hide();
  $('.car2').hide();
  $('.car3').hide();
  $('.car4').hide();

  $(".changeprice").on("click", function() {
    var currentid = this.id;
    changecarousel(currentid);
  });

  carValue = localStorage.getItem('carValue');
  if (carValue) {
    changecarousel(carValue);
  }
});

function changecarousel(id) {
  console.log(id);
  localStorage.setItem('carValue', id);
  switch (parseInt(id)) {
      ...
   }
 }
```